# How do i load a stored procedure on application startup when using HikariDataSource as the datasource object?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I am new to stored procedures and i'm trying to make my first stored procedure by going through [this stored procedure tutorial.](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-data/stored-procedure.html)

In the tutorial they are using an `EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder` object to create a datasource object and they are using the `addScript()` method to load the stored procedure into the database. However I am not using this Builder, instead I am instantiating a `HikariDataSource` object. This object has no way to load a stored procedure into the database. I don't want to be forced to load all my stored procedures manually into the database. So my question is, When using `HikariDataSource`, Is there a way to programmatically load all stored procedures into the database when they are not yet present?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to programmatically load all stored procedures into the database when they are not yet present?

You can use Liquibase (database migration library) for it: [Change: ‘createProcedure’](https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/create_procedure.html). The library is perfectly supported by Spring Boot. Maybe this tutorial will be usefull: [Use Liquibase to Safely Evolve Your Database Schema](https://www.baeldung.com/liquibase-refactor-schema-of-java-app).